# Create a release that will promote only the relevant submodules

Tags: maven, pom.xml, git-submodules, maven-release-plugin, parent-pom

I have a root pom that have multiprojects.
When doing `mvn release:prepare` a tag is being created were all the SNAPSHOT changed to numbers.
Is there a way to create a release that will promote only the projects that had changed from the last release without editing / supplying the release.properties?

Right now the `release:prepare` is promoting each pom version to the next level no matter if there were no changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has no way to identify which module has changed since the last release, so no, there is no easy way to do it.

A possible workaround would be to use profiles, and that you create a profile "release" which contains only the submodules you want to be released and all the others are in another that is active by default.

So when you want to perform a release, you specify the release profile (using `-P profile` appended to your command) and only those will be taken into account.

Comment: it should be dynamically, if I'll create a profile for the relevant submodules then I will need to change it base on the changes for each release.
is there a way to keep the old version number and then I will modify them by myself according to the change?